# Commit msg hook, how active?

Tags: hook, githooks

I want use commit msg hook to validate my commit msgs, without node, commitlint and husky. I think that it is possible only with hooks, properly commit-msg hook.

I´m using window environment. I'm try use commit-msg hook, in my folder hooks of my repo, i clean .sample and changes de scrit with code that i want to validade commit msg. After verify and accert hooksPath with:

```
git config core.hooksPath .hooks
```

and

```
git config --get core.hooksPath
```

i see in same cases that it is necessary run command:

```
chmod +x commit-msg
```

to turn the script executable but isn´t possible in windows.
so my problem is:

```
git hook run .git\hooks\commit-msg
error: cannot find a hook named .git\hooks\commit-msg
```

the hook not are runnig with git commit command.
can you Help me please.

Comment: maybe `git hook run commit-msg` ?

Comment: I tried to, give the same error. thanks